# Declare Enum within a method .Net

Tags: .net, enums

Can I declare a type as Enum within my method in .NET? How can I do that? This is because, Sometimes, I just need a quick temporary Enum for code readability within a method, and this Enum is not used anywhere else outside the method.

Comment: In what way would that make anything more readable?

Comment: says, inside my method, I have a calculated variable, =1 means Short term deflection, = 2 means Long-terms deflections, = 3 means total deflection (It's deflection of a concrete beam). I want to temporary create Enum for such a case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do some crazy code where you use `Emit` to generate a c# enum during runtime, but that seems like overkill.

An `enum` gets compiled down into a class of constant values. If you want a group of constant values within a method, just declare local const variables:

```
public void Foo(int value)
{
    const deflection_short = 1;
    const deflection_long = 2;
    const deflection_concrete = 3;

    if (value == deflection_short) { ... }
}
```

The compiler will simply replace all of the usages with the actual constant value, which is very efficient, and you'll get to use friendly names instead of magic numbers. Though, with real enums that exist outside of the local method you would get the ability to pass in arguments that are just as friendly (i.e. `Foo(Deflection deflection) { ... }`)

Comment: "You could do some crazy code where you use Emit to generate a c# enum during runtime ..." But that wouldn't help the OP since the generated constants couldn't be part of his program, could they?